# Is there a simple way to receive statistics for my AIR app (as which frame is the most readed)?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air, statistics

I've got an AIR app with 5 frames and some AS3 code on each frame :

[My scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYJ11.png)

Is there a simple way to put a statistic analytic of the app that send me stats like which frame is the most visited ?

Comment: Google universal analytics by zwetan @ https://github.com/zwetan/as3-universal-analytics

Comment: I'm trying to use [this](http://www.devactionscript.com/free-ane/google-analytics-ane-adobe-air-native-extensions-for-android/) cause it seems really simple to use but I can't figure out how to import "FreeAneGoogleAnalytics" as, if I paste the code, Flash is saying : Error 1172 FreeAneGoogleAnalytics not found.

Comment: IMHO I would use the uni-analytics project as it does not require an ANE as it is written in 'pure' AS3. Never used the one that you linked, but you will need to import the `.swc` and the android-based `.ane` into your project.

Comment: Thx. And how can I hide the overlay analytics on my AIR app ? [this](http://hpics.li/3bfda8f)

Comment: I put false in this line : `var tracker:AnalyticsTracker = new GATracker( this, "****", "AppName", false );`  but it seems that it disable the analytics and doesn't send anything to Google. I can't hide the overlay AND sending data ?

Comment: `GATracker`? Are you using the old tracker library? There are classes: `SimplestTracker` , `WebTracker`,  `AppTracker`, etc... Since you are building an AIR app, use `AppTracker`...

Comment: Tried  the uni-analytics project and I don't know how to use it... Is there a tutorial somewhere ? (or can you give me a small exemple how can I use it ?)  (what to `import`, where can I put `tracker.trackPageview`..etc ? )

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way IMO: have the frame load a php page when the user navs to a new frame.

You could send a var using [URLVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html) about the current frame (the time using Date(), the previous frame if you're keeping track of that using a variable of sorts, ext). You could also do this when a user clicks a button in a certain frame. You can use an analytics API instead as suggested in the comments...